# How to identify when a certain image disappear

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm doing an opencv project which needs to detect a image on the screen, which will disappear after some time it shows up. It needs to save the most amount of frames possible while the image is showing, and stop when it disappears. I plan to use the data collected to do a ConvNet, so the more frames I can capture, the better.

I was using template matching full-screen to search for the image and to identify when it disappears, but I was only capturing about 30% of the total frames, with the screen at 30FPS.

Wanting to increase frame capture rate, I changed to searching full-screen with template matching until the image was found, and then the area for searching was reduced to the coordinates found of the image with a little margin, so the program could identify when the image disapeared using a lot less resources (because of a very smaller área to check if the image was still there). This allowed me to capture 60% of the frames.

However I want to know, can I do something else to allow me to optimize my program? I feel like doing template matching for every frame is overkill. Is object tracking better in this case, or it won't even work because the image disapears?

PS: the image stays for about 7~10 seconds on the screen and takes about the same time to pop up again.

Comment: Is your program using all of the CPU cores available? What's the overall utilization? | What if you downsize your input image as well as the template. Can you reliably find it even then?

Comment: @DanMašek what do you mean with downsize the images? Resizing them to smaller sizes and then doing the matching? For now it is using only 1 core, I will try to increase it (never did it before)

Comment: By downsizing I mean scale (resize) them to half the size or even smaller. (and same with the template) Assuming you can still get a good enough match, it will mean you have to do significantly fewer calculations.

Comment: The maximum I could downsize is to 33%, with no visible increase (61%) and unstable capture. CPU usage is at ~20% of my i7-7500u. I think I will let it at 60%. I don't believe its a nice idea to increase the CPU load too much (I don't even know how to do it even if I wanted) and using multiprocessing will be just too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended using numpy to save the captured frames and reached 99% efficiency with the reduced area, no resizing of the images or multiprocessing.